# Finding the function $z=f(x,y)$ based on given conditions

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $z=x^2+7x+3$ when $y=-1$
If $z=y^3+4y^2+6y+38$ when $x=2$

Is it possible to find the function for $z=f(x,y)$?
How does one go about solving the answer?
What is the answer?

Comment: What would the value be in $(2,-1)$?

Comment: @Henrik: One gives $21$, the other gives $35$. Hence $f(2,-1)$ is undefined.

Comment: Yeah, I somehow read $7x^2$, but as there already is an $x^2$ term, I guess that's a highly unlikely typo.

Comment: @Henrik  here's an updated version of my question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2494804/496773

Comment: @quasi Can you check it out as well.

Comment: I realised that I had left out some information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(2,-1)$ had been well-defined, and you had no other requirements there would be infinitely many functions satisfying that.

Comment: As noted in the comments, $f(2,-1)$ is not well-defined.