# Finding the function $z=f(x,y)$ with given information

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $z=x^2+7x+3$ when $y=−1$
If $z=y^3+4y^2+6y+24$ when $x=2$

$f(2,-1)=21$
$0 \le z \le 100$

Is it possible to find the function for $z=f(x,y)$?
How does one go about solving the answer?
What is the answer?
If there are infinite solutions what kind of information/constraints is needed to obtain a specific function in the form of $z=f(x,y)$

Comment: Is it a typo that you have $3z$ in the first expression?

Comment: @Henrik Yes it is a typo

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the $z$ in the first expression just shouldn't be there!

There's still an infinite number of solutions. Two examples would be:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x^2+7x+3 & \text{when }y=-1\\
y^3+4y^2+6y+24 & \text{when }x=2\\
42 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x^2+7x+3 & \text{when }y=-1\\
y^3+4y^2+6y+24 & \text{when }x=2\\
75 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

To find out which requirements would give a unique solution is qute hard, but some that would bring you further includes: continuity, $n$ times differentiability (with continuous derivative), concavity, being a polynomial of degree $<m$, ...

Comment: The equation that I am looking for is z=x2+7x+y3+4y2+6y+6z=x2+7x+y3+4y2+6y+6. Is it not possible to work back calculate this equation from the question above?

Comment: That is just the addition of the non-constant terms of the two expressions, with a new constant term that isn't hard to derive to match the value of the "new" terms on the given lines. That is one of the infinitely many solutions. It's one (but there's still - I believe, infinitely - many) that are continuous. It's also a polynomial of degree 2 in $x$ and 3 in $y$, there might not be many of those. (I'm not sure)

Comment: It's a question of taste, but to me "isn't hard" is still harder than just selecting a random value as the value off the given lines.